# SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

This error occurs when data binding a repeater:
SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    topicid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["topic".ToString()]);

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        MusicForumDataContext db = new MusicForumDataContext();

        var query = from p in db.posts
                    where p.categoryid == NAME
                    select p;
        rptposts.DataSource = query;
        rptposts.DataBind(); <---- ERROR
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

NTEXT, TEXT and IMAGE types are deprecated and must be replaced with the NVARCHAR(MAX), VARCHAR(MAX) and VARBINARY(MAX) types. The new types support string operators, including equality comparison.

XML can never be compared as a string. XML snippets can be written in thousands of ways and result semantically in the same XML. Just think at namespaces and how they can be declared however one likes.