# wp8 local database issue

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-8

I have created local database in windows phone 8 app. I have 4 fields.

```
userID - int
Username - string 
FileName - string 
FileByte - byte[]
```

What I am doing is trying to update the FileByte column. But when I update the column I get exception `SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types.`

Here is my `DataTable`

```
[Table]
public class UserFilesDetailsTable : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    // Define ID: private field, public property, and database column.
    private int _userID;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int userID
    {
        get { return _userID; }
        set
        {
            if (_userID != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("userID");
                _userID = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("userID");
            }
        }
    }

    // Define item name: private field, public property, and database column.
    private string _Username;
    [Column(DbType = "NVarChar(100) NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Username
    {
        get { return _Username; }
        set
        {
            if (_Username != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Username");
                _Username = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Username");
            }
        }
    }

    // Define item name: private field, public property, and database column.
    private string _Filename;
    [Column(DbType = "NVarChar(100) NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Filename
    {
        get { return _Filename; }
        set
        {
            if (_Filename != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Filename");
                _Filename = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Filename");
            }
        }
    }

    // Define item name: private field, public property, and database column.
    private byte[] _Filebytes;
    [Column(DbType = "image")]
    public byte[] Filebytes
    {
        get { return _Filebytes; }
        set
        {
            if (_Filebytes != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Filebytes");
                _Filebytes = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Filebytes");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Used to notify that a property changed
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanging Members

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    // Used to notify that a property is about to change
    private void NotifyPropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanging != null)
        {
            PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here my Update **query**

```
public void addFiles(int userID, string userName, string fileName, byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!(databaseTablesDB.usersFileDetailsTable.Where(f => f.Filename == fileName).Any()))
            {
                databaseTablesDB.usersFileDetailsTable.InsertOnSubmit(new UserFilesDetailsTable { userID = userID, Username = userName, Filename = fileName, Filebytes = fileBytes });
                // Save changes to the database.
                databaseTablesDB.SubmitChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                var fileDetails = (from file in databaseTablesDB.usersFileDetailsTable where file.Filename == fileName && file.Username == userName select file).FirstOrDefault();
                if (fileDetails != null)
                {
                    fileDetails.Filebytes = fileBytes;
                }
                databaseTablesDB.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

        }
    }
```

I am not getting where is the issue. Can some one please help to solve this?

Comment: Why do you have both fileName and fileByte fields for an image? Just keep the fileName field and in order to update your image overwrite it in the isolated storage.

Comment: @Pantelis Thanks for reply. Actually I want to save byte array of file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568976/sql-server-does-not-handle-comparison-of-ntext-text-xml-or-image-data-types). It suggests you change the type of your FileByte column to VARBINARY(MAX).

Comment: I change my data type according to this. But I am getting error while creating database. `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3,Token line offset = 23,Token in error = MAX ]`. Getting this error on `db.CreateDatabase();`

Comment: How can I create byte column in database ?

Comment: change [Column(DbType = "image")] to [Column(DbType = "VARBINARY(MAX)")]

Comment: I changed it like your suggestion. but it gives me an error `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 5,Token line offset = 25,Token in error = MAX ]`

Comment: My column look like `// Define item name: private field, public property, and database column.
        private byte[] _Filebytes;
        [Column(DbType = "VARBINARY(MAX)")]
        public byte[] Filebytes`