# LINQ result to object initializer

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with converting linq result to object.

I have a class called `Plant` and a database which contains information about it (for example name, latin name, habitats etc).
I want to create a new object from executed query and send it to another part of application. So I'm messing with this code:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext())
{

    var sPlant = (from p in dc.Plants where p.Name == plantName select new Plant
    {
        Name = p.Name,
        LatinName = p.LatinName, 
        Habitat = p.Habitat,
        LeafHarvesting = p.LeafHarvesting,
        FlowerHarvesting = p.FlowerHarvesting,
        FruitHarvesting = p.FruitHarvesting,
        RootHarvesting = p.RootHarvesting,
        Morphology = p.Morphology,
        Pharmacology = p.Pharmacology,
        Img = p.Img,
        GPSCoordinates = p.GPSCoordinates
    } 
);
```

But it doesn't convert result to a new `Plant` object.

Comment: What does happen? Do you get an error message? What is the output?

Comment: It's a `select`, so I guess this creates an `IEnumerable<Plant>` or something. Add a `First()`.

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Zielnik.Plant>' to 'Zielnik.Plant'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems that `Plant` is not part of the data store, you need to return an object that Linq to SQL can handle, to then create your `Plant` instance locally.

Start by querying for a list of anonymous objects containing the properties you need, and then only create your `Plant`. Add a [`First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) at the end to retrieve only one `Plant`:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var sPlant = (from p in dc.Plants where p.Name == plantName
        select new {
            Name = p.Name,
            LatinName = p.LatinName, 
            Habitat = p.Habitat,
            LeafHarvesting = p.LeafHarvesting,
            FlowerHarvesting = p.FlowerHarvesting,
            FruitHarvesting = p.FruitHarvesting,
            RootHarvesting = p.RootHarvesting,
            Morphology = p.Morphology,
            Pharmacology = p.Pharmacology,
            Img = p.Img,
            GPSCoordinates = p.GPSCoordinates
        }).AsEnumerable().Select(p => new Plant
        {
            Name = p.Name,
            LatinName = p.LatinName, 
            Habitat = p.Habitat,
            LeafHarvesting = p.LeafHarvesting,
            FlowerHarvesting = p.FlowerHarvesting,
            FruitHarvesting = p.FruitHarvesting,
            RootHarvesting = p.RootHarvesting,
            Morphology = p.Morphology,
            Pharmacology = p.Pharmacology,
            Img = p.Img,
            GPSCoordinates = p.GPSCoordinates
        }).First();
}
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll

Comment: explicit construction unit type "Zielnik.Plant" in the query is not allowed.

Comment: it results in the same exception

Comment: edited again... I'm a bit rusty, i'll have to find a way to test it.

Comment: it ended with "SQL Server doesn't provide comparing data types NText, Text, Xml ani Image.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1568976/1679537) or [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1813435.aspx?+SQL+Server+does+not+handle+comparison+of+NText+Text+Xml+or+Image+data+types+). I guess the problem comes from your `Img` field.

Comment: I changed all datatypes in database to nvarchar(max) Code is getting the error "explicit construction type Zielnik.plant in the query is not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Use First or FirstOrDefault function to get the object. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq) to get the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is suppose to return multiple results, use .TOList(). If you want to take first row only,use FirstOrDefault()